# Windows 10 Dark Colored, Touch based App similar to dropbox

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, dropbox, dark-theme

I like converting online article text to mp3s during the day and listening to them before bed

I save those files to dropbox so I can access them on different devices

Opening dropbox without using the windows 10 dropbox app results in opening default windows 10 file explorer, which has a white background and can't be changed even after you change the color from right click on desktop -> personalize

The dropbox app for windows 10 is very nice since I use a surface tablet. But dropbox has bright colors which are not so pleasant before bed. Other apps like the audible app for windows 10 use dark colors which is great before bed.

What software recommendation would be best to find what I'm looking?

Specifications
- Windows 10 Surface Pro 3 
- Cloud based online storage app like dropbox where I can save an mp3 file to it on any computer 
- has a touch version with dark colors 
- If the app could also work for android or ios that would be great too (I have a samsung s7 phone and an ipad air 2)